# Best way to store images and video on azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

What is the best secure way to store media files on Azure?

It is images and video files, and they are related to a user and need to be secured for unauthorized access. It have to have a good performance and load times need to be low.

The stored files is used on a website!

Is it the database blob solution? 
Or file system approach?

Witch name giving system or ways is the best?

Answer (score 9):

[BlobStorage](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) is very much the 'cloud' way for storage purposes and relatively inexpensive.

BlobStorage can be secured or unsecured with access to files through your application streaming the files directly or even better, by providing limited / secured access to the files in BlobStorage through the use of [Shared Access Signatures](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/).